# Cakephp error in php error log

Tags: php, cakephp

I have transferred over a site to a new hosting provider and it's giving me below PHP errors:

```
[15-Dec-2011 16:15:41] PHP Warning:  include(cake/bootstrap.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/stor7-wc2-dfw1/517847/517853/dashboard.blinkpocket.com/web/content/app/webroot/index.php on line 76
[15-Dec-2011 16:15:41] PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'cake/bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/wmetools/public_html/blink:/mnt/stor7-wc2-dfw1/517847/517853/dashboard.blinkpocket.com/web/content/app/:.:/usr/share/pear') in /mnt/stor7-wc2-dfw1/517847/517853/dashboard.blinkpocket.com/web/content/app/webroot/index.php on line 76
[15-Dec-2011 16:15:41] PHP Fatal error:  CakePHP core could not be found.  Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php.  It should point to the directory containing your /cake core directory and your /vendors root directory. in /mnt/stor7-wc2-dfw1/517847/517853/dashboard.blinkpocket.com/web/content/app/webroot/index.php on line 77
```

Is there a way we can fix above issue?

Comment: Dear John, we can't give a check without any source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you didn't copy your cake/app/config folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read on CakePHP [installation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html) and [deployment](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html) for further information on how to deploy your website on a webserver.